# Component name is not unique, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in Jira Scriptrunner for the line issueLinkManager.createIssueLink

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am writing code to create a new linked issue and I am having the following error thrown

[image]

```
void createFeature(Issue issue, Collection<ProjectComponent> componentList){

def issueLinkManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager()

def authenticationContext = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext

def issueFactory = ComponentAccessor.getIssueFactory()

def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()

def userManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserUtil()

 def currentUserObj = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser();

long issueLinkType= 10070 as long

long sequence =1 as long

long newissueTypeID= 19 as long

long myissueID= issue.getId() as long

// the key of the project under which the version will get created

 final String projectKey = "SF"

// the start date - optional

final Date startDate = null

// the release date - optional

final Date releaseDate = null

// a description for the new version - optional

final String description = null

// id of the version to schedule after the given version object - optional

final Long scheduleAfterVersion = null

// true if this is a released version

final boolean released = false

def project = ComponentAccessor.projectManager.getProjectObjByKey(projectKey)

assert project : "Could not find project with key $projectKey"

def projectComponentManager = ComponentAccessor.getProjectComponentManager()

         int counter=0

        for(ProjectComponent component: componentList){

                    MutableIssue newissue= ComponentAccessor.issueFactory.getIssue()

                                        //set values

                    newissue.setIssueTypeId("19") 

                    newissue.setSummary("MOUNA CAMELIA")

                    newissue.setDescription("MOUNA CAMELIA")

                    newissue.reporter = issue.getReporter()

                     // you can *add* labels like this (using the syntax above would overwrite all labels)

                    // newissue = newissue.update {

                    //     setLabels {

                    //         add('SF-Child')

                    //     }

                    // }

                    String componentName= component.getName()

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 5 "+component)

                    def shortenedComponentName = componentName.substring(componentName.indexOf("-")+1) 

                    def projectName = componentName.substring(0, componentName.indexOf("-")) 

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 6 projectName--"+projectName+"--" )

                    def newIssueproject = ComponentAccessor.projectManager.getProjectObjByKey(projectName)

                    newissue.setProjectObject(newIssueproject)

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA ISSUE GET VERSIONS "+newIssueproject.getVersions()+"-========= ")

                    List<String> newIssueProjectVersionIDs= new ArrayList<String>()

                    for(Version myver: newIssueproject.getVersions()){

                            newIssueProjectVersionIDs.add(myver.getName())

                    }

                     log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA newIssueProjectVersionIDs "+newIssueProjectVersionIDs+"-========= ")

                 

                    def mynewVersions = new ArrayList <Version> ()

                    for( Version v: issue.getFixVersions()){

                        log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA VERSION V "+v.getName())

                        if(newIssueProjectVersionIDs.contains(v.getName())){

                                 Version mynewVersion= ComponentAccessor.versionManager.createVersion(v.getName()+"-Inbox", startDate, releaseDate, description, newIssueproject.id, scheduleAfterVersion, released)

                                 mynewVersions.add(mynewVersion)

                                 log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA TRUE")

                        }else{

                               log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA FALSE")

                        }

                

                    }

                    newissue.setFixVersions(mynewVersions)

                    def customField =  ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10790");// here replace the ID with ID of your custom field.

                     Integer value = issue.getCustomFieldValue(customField) as Integer; 

                    // def sampleTextField = getFieldByName(value)

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA VALUE "+value )

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 6 newIssueproject "+newIssueproject )

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 7 component.getDescription() "+component.getDescription() )

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 8  component.getLead() "+ component.getLead() )

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 9  component.assigneeType() "+ component.assigneeType )

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 10  component.getProjectId() "+ component.getProjectId() )

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 11--"+shortenedComponentName+"--")

                 

                     ProjectComponent newComponent = projectComponentManager.create(shortenedComponentName,component.getDescription(),

                   component.getLead(),component.getAssigneeType(),component.getProjectId())

                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 7 "+newComponent.getName())

                    List<ProjectComponent> mynewComponentList = new ArrayList<ProjectComponent>()

                    mynewComponentList.add(newComponent)

                    newissue.setComponent(mynewComponentList)

                  

                    log.warn(" MOUNA CAMELIA ==========================COMPONENT NUMBER "+counter +" "+component)

                           

                    def newIssueCreated = issueManager.createIssueObject(currentUserObj, newissue)

                    log.warn(" MOUNA CAMELIA 2 ==========================")

                    long newIssueCreatedID= newIssueCreated.getId() as long

                    

                    def labelManager = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(LabelManager)

                    labelManager.addLabel(authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser(), newIssueCreatedID, "SF-Child", false)

                   

                    def issueToLink = issueManager.getIssueObject(newIssueCreated.getKey())

                    log.warn(" MOUNA CAMELIA 4 ==========================")

                     log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA ===== myissueID ====="+ myissueID+" =====newissueTypeID ====="+newIssueCreated.getId()

                      +" =====issueLinkType ====="+issueLinkType

                     +" =====sequence ====="+ sequence +" =====authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser() ====="+authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser()

                     )      

                     

                    issueLinkManager.createIssueLink(newIssueCreatedID, myissueID, issueLinkType, sequence, authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())

                 

                    counter++

                             

         }

}
```

The line causing the problem is:

```
issueLinkManager.createIssueLink(newIssueCreatedID, myissueID, issueLinkType, sequence, authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())
```

The error says:
**Script function failed on Automation for Jira rule:
Script function failed on Automation for Jira rule: UpdateExecutionSummary , file: SuperFeature/rest_superFeatureGenerator.groovy, error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component name = 'WCPOS' is not unique**
Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: I would guess that your shortenedComponentName is not unique. Are you supposed to be creating a new component in your script instead of fetching an existing one?

Comment: it is unique, I have checked

Comment: Why is the code so messy and has so many unused variables? For example there is `long newissueTypeID= 19 as long` but then it isn't used: `newissue.setIssueTypeId("19") ` Cleaning it up a bit may reveal the issue. Furthermore, I've identified the language as groovy so you should add that tag to your question. Furthermore, it helps if you post only the minimum code required to create the problem on stack overflow. !mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                     ProjectComponent newComponent =null

                    List<ProjectComponent> newList = new ArrayList<>(newIssueproject.getComponents());
                    def found = newList.any { it.getName().equals(shortenedComponentName)}
                    
                    log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA found--"+found+"--NEW LIST SIZE: "+newList)

                    if(found ){
                        newComponent=projectComponentManager.findByComponentName(newIssueproject.getId(), shortenedComponentName)
                    }
                    else {
                        try{
                                    newComponent = projectComponentManager.create(shortenedComponentName,component.getDescription(),
                                    component.getLead(),component.getAssigneeType(),newIssueproject.getId())
                                        log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA HELLO 7 "+newComponent.getName())
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA EXCEPTION "+e)
                        }
                    
                    }
```